# Excel formula to sum up values from certain rows with the same number and then divide the sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

[image: Excel Image]

I am trying to write a formula that will help sum up the quantity of the items with the same material number and then divide the quantity of that row with the sum of the material with the same material number divide by 100. Sometimes it can be the sum from 3 row but some time it can be the sum of 4/5/6 rows.

Example: Material Description `AA`
In box D2 `= (A2/(A2+A5))*100`

This formula works if there are only a few rows, but my main table have over 19000 rows. So, I need a dynamic formula instead. Do assist to help and let me know if you require more example.

[image: Image 2]

Here is the expected outcome
[image: Expected outcome]

So for material "50066196" the sum of those 4 rows is 1000. So i have to convert this sum to 100 instead of 1000.
For the overall data, some of the material have a sum of more that or less than 1000.

Comment: have you looked at sumif() sumifs() averageif() averageifs()

Comment: Tried sumif() but seems to work only for the first group of material. When i drag down the formula, it is wrong. Maybe im doing it wrongly.

Comment: Show example data and your use of sumif() then.

Comment: Sorry i was using IF only. "=IF((A2=A3),"",(C2/(SUM($C$2:C2)))*100)" Added image in the original post Image 2.
If using SUMIF can you help to provide the formula?

Comment: Please, clarify. First, you say *sum up the quantity of the items with the same material number and then divide the quantity of that row with the sum of the material with the same material number divide by 100* but then your formula later on is `(A2/(A2+A5))*100` which **does not match** your previous need. Show som real expected outputs and add easy data to copy table using [Table Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Is 'Material' id number also used in the filtering or calculation?

Comment: I'm sorry but your expected output just divided by 10 adjacent cell in all cases. What do you really want and how do you manually calculate it? **Your question and clarification does not fit your expected outcome**.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without any data to copy (images are not very useful...) have a look at this:

[image]

To save a bit of typing:

```
SUMIF($A$2:$A$19,F2,$C$2:$C$19)

UNIQUE(A2:A19)
```

For the divide if I understand what you mean then you can do a count using countif() - same ranges etc as the sumif().

Also you could use averageif() to get the same result as using the sum with count:

```
AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$19,F2,$C$2:$C$19)
```

Comment: Sorry i think i explained wrongly. I have attached a new image to describe the expected outcome

Comment: @JoshuaOng then edit the calculations I show - the techniques are there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep everything as you have it now:

[image]

Formula used in B2 and dragged down:

```
=IF(B2=B3,"",C2/(SUMIF($B$2:B2,B2,$C$2:C2))*100)
```

Over 19k rows, it didn't take that long to calculate.

**EDIT:**

```
=ROUND(C2/SUMIF(B:B,B2,C:C)*100,3)
```

Comment: Sorry i think i explained wrongly. I have attached a new image to describe the expected outcome